# Can I use progress bar and swipe refresh at the same fragment?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

Progressbar, progressbar is firstly used when data is loading from web.

Swipe refresh layout, it's used when more data is loading.

Before I added swipe refresh layout, progressbar was fine.
After adding swipe refresh layout, progressbar doesn't work.
Is it possible to use both of them?

thank to you.

Comment: Of course you can use both of them. Paste your code here so that we'd able to debug it.

Comment: thanks guy. I got it using Relative Layout as parent of SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: Some useful design rules : https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-swipe-to-refresh.html

Answer (score 0):

With **refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true/false)** you can remove progress bar entirely from your layout.